# Unable to install Enterprise app on iPhone 11 pro max

Tags: ios, ios13.3, xcode11.2.1

We are able to install `Enterprise app` on `iPhone 8`, `iPhone 7`, `iPhone XR` with `iOS 13.3 OS version`. But the same app unable to install on `iPhone 11 pro max`. Getting 'Unable to install app' error message.

Any idea why this has happened? Any apple privacy changes have been updated for `iPhone 11 pro max`?

Comment: Is your app builded with all needed architecture ? Otherwise you can access the device console log to have more details

Comment: created IPA using Xcode 10.2.

Comment: Check in your builds settings if "build active architecture only" is set to NO for the build variant your are using

Comment: It is "build active architecture only" = NO

Comment: And "valid architectures" are added as arm64, arm64e, arm7, arm7s.

Comment: So you have to plug your iPhone to the mac, open the Console app and read the install log

Comment: Actually, I don't have iPhone 11 pro max. Some customer raised this issue. so needs to find out why it doesn't work.